# ¿Cómo comparar dos valores de dos bases de datos?

Tags: c#, sql, base-de-datos

Quiero obtener el número de "Customer" de la base de datos SQL y el número de "customer" de otra base de datos que tengo en PostgreSQL para compararlos y retornar verdadero o falso. Mi pregunta es, cómo puedo hacer la comparación de ambos correctamente? 
Tengo este código, pero en la base de datos SQL tengo 69 Customer, y en la otra base de datos no tengo nada. Pero, al ejecutar el código, verifiqué qué datos arrojaba y en ambas variables (lastID y lastClient) es el mismo valor, 69.
Debería de ser lastID = 69 y lastClient = 0 pero no entiendo porqué le asigna 69 a ambas variables.

```
 public static bool compareNumberOfUsers()
    {
        string connString = String.Format("Server={0};Port={1};" +
           "User Id={2};Password={3};Database={4};"
           , DataDB.server, DataDB.port, DataDB.user, DataDB.password, DataDB.database
           );

        try
        {
            //Sql Connection
            // Build Connection string
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            builder.DataSource = SQL_HOST;
            builder.UserID = SQL_USER;
            builder.Password = SQL_PSWD;
            builder.InitialCatalog = SQL_DB;

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                string sql = "select count(Customer) as lastID from Customer;";

                using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString))
                {

                    conn.Open();


                    string psql = "select count(customer) as lastClient from clients;";

                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                    {
                        int lastID = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
                        using (var pcommand = new NpgsqlCommand(psql, conn))
                        {


                            int lastClient = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());


                            if (lastID > lastClient)
                            {

                                return true;

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return false;


                            }


                        }
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                    connection.Close();


                }
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Estás conectandote a la primera base de datos dos veces, pues estás usando command y no pcommand:

```
...
using (var pcommand = new NpgsqlCommand(psql, conn))
{
   // Aquí tendrías que cambiarlo por pcommand
   int lastClient = Convert.ToInt32(pcommand.ExecuteScalar());

   if (lastID > lastClient)
   {
      return true;
   }
   else
   {
      return false;
   }
}
conn.Close();

...
```